# Why is this javascript if statement/for-loop syntactically incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a java-programmer by trade. Why is this for-loop syntactically incorrect? (The problem is in the if-statement)

```
var wind = "thisisatest";
var k=false;
for (i = 0; i < wind.length; i++) {
 if ((wind.charAt(i)='?') && (wind.charAt(i+1)='s') && (wind.charAt(i+2)='1')) {k=true;} 
}
```

Comment: [`=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) is used for assignment and a method call cannot be assigned to. To compare, use [`==` or `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Side note: You can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) – `var k = wind.indexOf("?s1") > -1;`

Comment: You can also use `wind.substr(i, 3) == '?s1'`

Answer (score 0):

`wind.charAt(i)='?'` do you mean to say `==`? You can't assign a value to a method return type.

Besides that, what happens when `i` reaches `wind.length-1` (last char)? Will it try to access the character next to that? And the one after that? There are no more characters. It should go `i < wind.length - 2`